# Methods to validate a hidden markov model

Tags: cross-validation, hidden-markov-model, model-evaluation

What specific metrics should one use to evaluate the performance of a hidden markov model where the training is unsuperivsed?

In essence how does one cross validate a model correctly, with regards to a pre-specified number of states?

Furthermore, can you perform feature selection when the training is unsupervised with these metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) What do u mean by unsupervised in HMM ?
Model fitting can be seen in term of AIC/BIC values. Model takes actual values in Forward Backward Algo for parameter estimation so like other models you don't have anything like predicted and actual values to compare accuracy.

2) You can have test set where you compare actual and foretasted values(by calculating next hidden states with their participation probability and then multiplying it with emission probability/distribution.)

Comment: Unsupervised as in there is no target state specified. see https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn  "hmmlearn is a set of algorithms for unsupervised learning and inference of Hidden Markov Models. For supervised learning learning of HMMs and similar models see seqlearn."

Comment: Is there anywhere I can see part 2) being done as a practical example?

Comment: https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.in/2017/02/hidden-markov-model-session-1.html, this will help. Remember : -- output value=  sigma (hidden state probability* mean of Emission distribution)